# Is a new object created (in helper class) every time a static method is invoked?

Tags: java, class

The general question would be, if there is an object created (globally) in **class A**, is a new object inside **class A** created every time any static method is invoked by a different class?

My guess is yes since the statement itself creating the object but I could not find any clarification on this specific situation (maybe because it's a dumb question).

```
public class Helper {
      private static Object x = new Object();

      public static void method1(){
            //uses x
      }

      public static void method2(){
            //uses x
      }

}
```

*The main class that uses Helper*

```
public class Main{

     public static void main(String[] args){
           Helper.method1();
           Helper.method2();
     }
}
```

In the above example, have 2 Objects been created due to those invocations? ***(not asking if there were 2 Helper objects created)***

I could probably rethink the design of the helper class but this made me want to get an answer to the initial question.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why do you think 2 Objects would be created ? There is only 1, created by `Object x = new Object();`

Comment: Static variables are only initialized once, only one Object will be created.

Comment: @AjJohnson Technically not totally true. Static variables are initialized when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

From the JLS [8.3.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1)

> If a field is declared static, there exists **exactly one incarnation of the field**, no matter how many instances (possibly zero) of the class may eventually be created. A static field, sometimes called a class variable, is incarnated when the class is initialized ([§12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)).

Thus, the object is created only once, since `static` fields are created only once.

Comment: But the question is not how many times the field exists but how many times it is called.

Comment: quoting the OP *In the above example, have 2 Objects been created due to those invocations?* @m0skit0

Comment: Objects and fields are different things. 2 Objects can be created and assigned to the same field.

Comment: @m0skit0 so you suggest more than 1 Object is created ? How ?

Comment: No, in theory, not in the example provided. What I mean simply is that the relevant part of the JLS is *"A static field [...] is incarnated when the class is initialized"*.

Comment: @Shashwat thanks, the reason why I thought there could be a possibility of 2 objects created is because I did not understand how the classes were loaded and initialized.

Comment: @essem10 sure, pleased to help.

Answer (score -1):

Process is as follows (simplified):

1. `Main` class is loaded
2. Static initialization is called for Main, but there's nothing to do
3. `Main.main()` method is called
4. `Helper` class is loaded
5. Static initialization is called for Helper, so `x = new Object()` is called
6. `Helper.method1()` is called
7. `Helper.method2()` is called

Comment: so the class Helper is loaded once when the main() is executed? and when invoking the methods, the methods are referencing the same static Object?

Comment: @essem10 Yes, correct. Note that classes could be loaded earlier, this is just a simplified example so you understand when the field is initialized and why it is initialized only once.